# How to handle products in Prestashop custom pages

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have my custom page to use as a landing page.  I did creating PHP files, Controller, php (root) and tpl.

Now, I need to get the products at this page, either a category or a single product. The questions are: how do I get the products from this site? There are some tutorial or documentation for the handling of products?

PD: Im using PS 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have lot of ways to get products by some criterios. First: just use DB query in PHP file and get list of products from MYSQL , assign your array and print it in .TPL FILE:

```
`$sql = "SELECT a FROM b WHERE ab=ba....";
$result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

$custProductList=array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
take all you need
}

$this->context->smarty->assign("custProductList", $custProductList);`
```

Now use it in TPL file.

U can use this easily. Foreach custProductList array from X to Y and print data which is usefull to you.

If you have custom page u can give a custom CSS.